# What does the `and` keyword mean in OCaml?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm mystified by the `and` keyword in OCaml. Looking through [this code](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/hack/src/typing/typing_env.ml#L61), I see

```
type env = {
    (* fields for a local environment described here *)
}

and genv {
    (* fields for a global environment here *)
}
```

then [later](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/hack/src/typing/typing_env.ml#L336),

```
let rec debug stack env (r, ty) = (* a function definition *)

and debugl stack env x = (* another function definition *)
```

What's going on here? Does the `and` keyword just copy the last `type`, `let`, or `let rec` statement? Is there such thing as an `and rec` statement? Why would I want to use `and` instead of just typing `let` or `type`, making my code less brittle to refactoring? Is there anything else I should know about?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `and` keyword is used either to avoid multiple `let` (first example, I never use it for this but why not) or for mutually recursive definitions of types, functions, modules...

As you can see in your second example :

```
let rec debug stack env (r, ty) =
   ...
   | Tunresolved tyl -> o "intersect("; debugl stack env tyl; o ")"
   ...
 
 and debugl stack env x =
   ...
   | [x] -> debug stack env x
   ...
```

`debug` calls `debugl` and vice versa. So the `and` is allowing that.

[EDIT] It bothered me not to give a proper example so here is one example that you'll often see :

```ml
let rec is_even x =
  if x = 0 then true else is_odd (x - 1)
and is_odd x =
  if x = 0 then false else is_even (x - 1)

(* second version *)

let rec is_even x =
  x = 0 || is_odd (x - 1)
and is_odd x =
  x <> 0 && is_even (x - 1)
```

(You can find this example [here](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variables-and-functions.html#recursive-functions))

For mutually recursive types, it's harder to find a configuration but following [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) we would define `trees` and `forests` as follow

```
 type 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a forest
 and 'a forest = Nil | Cons of 'a tree * 'a forest
```

As an example, a forest composed of the empty tree, the singleton tree labeled `a` and a two nodes tree with labels `b` and `c` would then be represented as :

```
 let f1 = Cons (Empty, (* Empty tree *)
             Cons (Node ('a',  (* Singleton tree *)
                         Nil), (* End of the first tree *)
                   Cons (Node ('b', (* Tree composed by 'b'... *)
                               Cons (Node ('c', (* and 'c' *)
                                           Nil), 
                                     Nil)
                           ),
                         Nil (* End ot the second tree *)
                     )
               )
         );;
```

And the size function (*counting the number of nodes in the forest*) would be :

```
let rec size_tree = function
  | Empty -> 0
  | Node (_, f) -> 1 + size_forest f
and size_forest = function
  | Nil -> 0
  | Cons (t, f) -> size_tree t + size_forest f
```

And we get

```
# size_forest f1;;
- : int = 3
```